# Вывод статей, дерево

Tags: sql, php, mysql

база mysql,
есть таблица

```
**page**

     - id
     - name
     - cat
```

и

```
**cat**
 - id
 - title
 - parent_id (NULL)
```

допустим выбрана категория, нужно вывести последние (id DESC) страницы (page)
с ограничением (LIMIT) из подкатегорий данной категории (ну соотв и из данной кат.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запрос выберет все записи которые соответствуют категории 123 и ее подкатегориям на 1 уровень вложенности.

```
SELECT *
FROM page p
LEFT JOIN cat с ON c.id = p.cat
WHERE
    (p.cat = 123) OR
    (c.parent_id = 123)
ORDER BY p.id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

На два уровня вложенности:

```
SELECT *
FROM page p
LEFT JOIN cat с1 ON c.id = p.cat
LEFT JOIN cat с2 ON c2.id = c1.parent_id
WHERE
    (p.cat = 123) OR
    (c1.parent_id = 123) OR
    (c2.parent_id = 123)
ORDER BY p.id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

К сожалению, этот тип деревьев не дает возможности выбирать все многократно-вложенное дерево в глубину без добавления LEFT JOIN на каждый следующий уровень.

Comment: Спасибо, KiTE!

Comment: Пожалуйста.

За карму спасибо, но не стоит ней разбрасываться. В качестве благодарности, достаточно поставить отметку "мне нравится", и, если ответ помог, принять его.